# Hide 200 responses from django runserver output

Tags: django

I'm Developing an app with Django with a mobile view. I had a problem in which I was not receiving in my cellphone certain javascript file. I was thinking that it would be great to hide all 200 responses from assets that the runserver commmand shows. This way it would be very simple to find cases like a 404.

Is there a way to do this with native django?

Comment: Well, you could use just `./manage.py runserver | grep -v 200` (which is not "native django")

Comment: Alternatively, although this is not "native django", you could set up remote debugging for your phone. A quick glance at the "Network" tab of either Firefox or Chrome would allow you to see a 404 (and much more) very easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2018-02-09**: this answer is no longer valid - nowadays development server messages go through logging subsystem - see [this file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a862af383969ade774f6b0fa1d331bc87b188b89/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L115). The easiest way to filter out 2xx messages seems to be not printing `info` loglevel. Note that this will also remove other output you might want to have.

---

It seems there is currently no options for configuring this in native django way. See [this file for more information](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5d263dee304fdaf95e18d2f0619d6925984a7f02/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L135). Log entries are written directly to `stderr`, instead of through [Django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) subsystem, so log filters are not usable.

To print everything except `200` responses, you could use

```
./manage.py runserver 2>&1 | grep -v " 200 "
```

- `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`.
- `-v` for grep inverses matches (outputs only lines not matching the expression)
- `" 200 "` is search expression for grep.